# Python Regex, re.sub, replacing multiple parts of pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I can't seem to find a good resource on this.. I am trying to do a simple re.place

I want to replace the part where its (.*?), but can't figure out the syntax on how to do this.. I know how to do it in PHP, so I've been messing around with what I think it could be based on that (which is why it has the $1 but I know that isn't correct in python).. I would appreciate if anyone can show the proper syntax, I'm not asking specifics for any certain string, just how I can replace something like this, or if it had more than 1 () area.. thanks

```
originalstring = 'fksf var:asfkj;'
pattern = '.*?var:(.*?);'
replacement_string='$1' + 'test'
replaced = re.sub(re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE), replacement_string, originalstring)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what you'd like the resulting string to be? Is it `asfkjtest`?

Comment: its just for an example, doesn't really matter what its for, I have a lot of regex stuff I did in php that I'm not trying to do in python so I just need to get the idea of how to do it down

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> originalstring = 'fksf var:asfkj;'
>>> pattern = '.*?var:(.*?);'
>>> pattern_obj = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
>>> replacement_string="\\1" + 'test'
>>> pattern_obj.sub(replacement_string, originalstring)
'asfkjtest'
```

Edit: The [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) can be pretty useful reference.

Comment: I know, I don't know why this is mentioned by everyone (about the python docs), I already know about these and have looked through them, I am posting here since I am still not clear on how to do this after consulting this, Python doesn't seem to be like PHP where it has a number of other resources on a topic like this so, after more searching, I felt I should post here (I'm not criticizing python for this, as I love it, its just an observation)

Comment: anyways, thanks for the help in posting the example, I do appreciate it

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that. Glad I could help!

Comment: Actually using a raw string allows you to use a single slash r'\1'

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r".*?var:(.*?);")
>>> regex.sub(r"\1test", "fksf var:asfkj;")
'asfkjtest'
```

Answer (score -2):

The python docs are online, and the one for the re module is here. http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

To answer your question though, Python uses \1 rather than $1 to refer to matched groups.